# Spring Security @PreAuthorize ByPass for specifc role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I'm working with Spring security policy and need help with a global role *SUPER* that must byPass all `@PreAuthorize` on endpoints when token has it. That's an endpoint example:

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("(hasAuthority('DOMAIN_FIND_ALL'))")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<List<DomainDTO>>> findAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(domainService.findAll());
}
```

The way i found for my Global role works, is like this

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("(hasAuthority('DOMAIN_FIND_ALL') or (hasAuthority('SUPER'))")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<List<DomainDTO>>> findAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(domainService.findAll());
}
```

But is too lengthy to implement every single endpoint of application the `(hasAuthority('SUPER')`, so i'm looking for a way to configure it in a global way, so that, if a token has that role, all endpoints are allowed.

What i've tried:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .otherStuffs..
              .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
              .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("SUPER");
}
```

But it does not work. Anyone has any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

For a more detailed explanation, take a look to the following [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) (mainly **section 6**). The code used as base of my response was:

[MySecurityExpressionRoot](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-boot-1/src/main/java/com/baeldung/roles/custom/security/MySecurityExpressionRoot.java)

[CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-boot-1/src/main/java/com/baeldung/roles/custom/security/CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java)

The following code works for me:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .otherStuffs..
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();  // hasRole("SUPER") isn't require
}
```

Override the default `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations` interface:

```
public class MySecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

  // Same properties than provided
  // link for MySecurityExpressionRoot
  ...

  public MySecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Authentication object cannot be null");
    }
    this.authentication = authentication;
  }

  // This is the ONLY change, as you can see the "SUPER" was added as allowed
  @Override
  public final boolean hasAuthority(String authority) {
    return this.hasAnyAuthority(authority, "SUPER");
  }

  // Rest of the code is the same than provided
  // link for MySecurityExpressionRoot
  ...
}
```

Now we need to add above class into Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration  // Required although not include in "source CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" class
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
  private final AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
    final MySecurityExpressionRoot root = new MySecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
    root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
    root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
    return root;
  }
}
```

Now you can verify it using the following dummy `GET` endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/add-new-user")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<String> addNewUser() {
    return new ResponseEntity("[add-new-user] Testing purpose", OK);
}
```

Any user with: `ADMIN` or `SUPER` roles will be able to access it.